# Forcing configure step with GNU autotools

Tags: makefile, gnu, autotools

I am running into an issue with autotools and thought somebody here could help.

I need to have *make* call *./configure* again after executing a particular make target. Here's my scenario: I have to call *make all_defconfig*, and as this changes a *.config* file in my directory which needs to be parsed by the *configure* script, I need to make sure that if *make* is called afterwards, the *configure* script is run again. Is there a way to force the configure step without ugly hacks?

Regards,
Sebastien

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Just call `configure` at the end of `make all_defconfig`:

```
all_defconfig: ...
        ...
        $(SHELL) ./config.status --recheck
```

I don't know enough about your build to guarantee that this won't loop... but I'm assuming it won't.